# What might be going wrong with my Vite - Reactjs website not coming up on Github Pages?

Tags: reactjs, vite, github-pages

I started a project this morning and I'm expected to share the live link with the tester.  The code was successfully built and deployed on GitHub actions, but unfortunately, it is not showing anything.

The attachment is the structure for the website that is not coming up on the Github pages even when the status code is 200 as could be seen in the second image.

[[image: The attachment is the structure for the website that is not coming up on the Github pages even when the status code is 200 as it could be seen in the second image.][1]]

The URL to it: https://lecon-a.github.io/getlinked/

[image]